# Aspect not getting called from Service class

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have a service class which has a method:

```
public void setDataSource(DynaFormReportFilterBean filterBean,Map parameterValues,List<Map<String,Object>> dynaFormStatusList)
```

I have created an Aspect class using `@Aspect` and i am using

```
@AfterReturning("execution(* org.bio.reports.service.jasper.DynaFormDataSourceReportService.setDataSource(..)) && args(bean,parameterValues,dynaFormStatusList)")
```

to call a method

```
public void afterReportAction(JoinPoint jp,
    final AbstractBean bean, final Map parameterValues,
    final List<Map<String, Object>> dynaFormStatusList) {//----Code here------//}`
```

When i run the code the Aspect class is not getting called.

here is the application-context entry:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

<!-- The below configuration is used to enable AspectJ support -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    <aop:include name="addressBookAuditLogAspect" />
    <aop:include name="inventoryAuditLogAspect" />
    <!-- aop:include name="shipmentAuditLogAspect" / -->
    <aop:include name="dynaAuditLogAspect" />
    <aop:include name="questionAuditLogAspect" />
    <aop:include name="reportAuditLogAspect" />
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>


 <!-- This bean defines the details about the TaskExecutor used for asynchronous invocation of method/s
     The values 3 properties mentioned can be changed as per the requirement
     Currently the values are specified for testing purpose  -->
<bean id="businessLogExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="25" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="100" />
 </bean>

 <!-- The below bean defines the  'DynaAuditLogAspect' class which will act as a bridge between Bio4D and Auditing utility -->
 <bean id="dynaAuditLogAspect" class="org.bio.audit.dynaforms.DynaAuditLogAspect">
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="businessLogExecutor" />
    <property name="bioExtensionDataDAO" ref="bioExtensionDataDAO" />
 </bean>
 <!-- The below bean defines the  'ReportAuditLogAspect' class which will act as a bridge between Bio4D and Auditing utility -->
<bean id="reportAuditLogAspect" class="org.bio.audit.reports.ReportAuditLogAspect">
<property name="taskExecutor1" ref="businessLogExecutor" />
    <property name="usersDAO" ref="usersDAO" />
 </bean>

<bean id="questionAuditLogAspect" class="org.bio.audit.dynaforms.QuestionAuditLogAspect">
 </bean>


 <!-- The below bean defines the  'ShipmentAuditLogAspect' class which will act as a bridge between Bio4D and Auditing utility -->
 <bean id="shipmentAuditLogAspect" class="org.bio.audit.bms.ShipmentAuditLogAspect">
    <property name="bmsTaskExecutor" ref="businessLogExecutor" />
    <property name="shipmentDAO" ref="shipmentDAO" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="inventoryAuditLogAspect" class="org.bio.audit.bms.InventoryAuditLogAspect">
 </bean>

  <!-- The below bean defines the  'AddressBookAuditLogAspect' class which will act as a bridge between Bio4D and Auditing utility -->
 <bean id="addressBookAuditLogAspect" class="org.bio.audit.administration.AddressBookAuditLogAspect"/> 
</beans>
```

Comment: Don't you need a space between `*` and `org` in your pointcut?

Comment: @sp00m yes there is a space between * and org still facing the issue

Comment: And why should it work. I see no `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` in your configuration. You need also to be aware of the fact that Spring AOP will only work for spring defined and controlled beans. If you have an unmanaged instance (created by Jasper for instance) it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you will need to declare  in configuration.
Also, since you are using @AfterReturning advice, this advice will get executed only if your target method does not throw any exception at runtime.